# Convert String Array to an Object in talend java code

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, talend

I have created a context variable called srcCols of type Object

I am assigning a string array to the context variable using this code.
The following assignment is done in tJava component

```
String[] cols = { "This","is","test" };
context.SrcCols = cols;
```

I am accessing the context variable in tJavaRow using the following code.

```
String[] Cols = (String[])context.SrcCols;
```

but when i run the job i get the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String

What will be the solution for this problem

PS: This job is a Talend Bigdata Spark Job.

Comment: type of context.SrcCols  ?

Comment: @RahulSingh Its Object

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with it (java 8)

```
Arrays.stream(objects).toArray(String[]::new);
```

in your case

```
String[] Cols = Arrays.stream(context.SrcCols).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: When i added this code , I am getting an error. "The Method Stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object) "

Comment: @Gian he is not using lists i guess that is the reason this might not work